# Azure File Share Check if multiple files exits

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-file-share

We are using Azure File Shares (File shares, not GPV2, meaning we're not using blobs or queues, just File Shares) to store our files.

We need to check if a list of file paths exist of not.

Is there a "bulk" version of `ShareFileClient.ExistsAsync` ?

What's the best workaround otherwise ?

We tried calling `Exists` on each path, each call in it's own task, but it takes too long to return (for 250 paths it takes around 25 seconds):

```
var tasks = paths.AsParallel().Select(p => Task.Run(() =>
{
  // share is a captured variable of type ShareClient
  var dir = share.GetDirectoryClient(GetDirName(p));
  var file = dir.GetFileClient(GetFileName(p));
  var result = file.Exists();
  return result.Value;
}));
```

Comment: 2 questions - 1) How many files are there in the directory? 2 - Do the files you want to check follow some naming pattern e.g. all of the files start with a common set of characters?

Comment: @GauravMantri 1) There are 8 directories in the file share, each directory having subdirectories...etc. the leaf directories contain around 20 files each. 2) Not really. There are some files starting with a common set of characters, but there is no possible logic to locate them.

Comment: Thanks. From your code above, it seems you want to check the existence of a file in a particular directory and not within that directory and its sub directories. Is that correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As such there's no direct way to check the existence of multiple files.

However, there is a workaround:

What you can do is list the files and subdirectories in a directory using [`GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync(ShareDirectoryGetFilesAndDirectoriesOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.sharedirectoryclient.getfilesanddirectoriesasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-sharedirectoryclient-getfilesanddirectoriesasync(azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharedirectorygetfilesanddirectoriesoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method. Once you get the list, you will loop over the list and and can check if a file by a particular name exists in a directory or not.

This will be much faster and cost efficient because you are making a single request to get the list of files instead of calling `FileClient.Exists` method on each file where each method call is a separate network request.